# R: Back out levels of a variable, given a matrix of growth rates

Tags: r

Good afternoon,

Suppose I have the following data frame:

```
> df <- data.frame(l=c(1,1.2, 1.56, 1.72, 2.06, 2.68, NA,NA,NA), g1=c(1.1,1.2,1.3,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.1,1.2,1.3),  g2=c(1.1,1.2,1.3,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.1,1.2,1.3))
```

The first column is the level of a variable, and columns 2 and 3 are growth rates of that variable (ignore the rounding error). Now, you will notice that for periods 7-9 I only have growth rates. What is the best way to back out what these growth rates imply for the level?

E.g for df[7,2], the calculation would be 2.06*1.1, for df[8,2] it would be df[7,2]*1.2 etc. I can easily write a loop, but I guess it is not the most "R-like" way of doing it...

[EDIT] Let me throw in a complication. Suppose, my data is in quarters. Rather than q/q growth rates, columns 2 and 3 are y/y growth rates. So, to use my previous example, df[7,2], the calculation would be 1.72*1.1, for df[8,2] it would be df[5,2]*1.2 etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: How about something along the lines of `df$newl <- c(df$l[1], df$l[1] * cumprod(df$g1[-1]))`

Comment: @user20650, you should post this, it is a decent answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
df$newl <- c(df$l[1] , df$l[1]  * cumprod(df$g1[-1]))
```

A couple of details

```
 head(df)
#      l  g1
# 1 1.00 1.1
# 2 1.20 1.2
# 3 1.56 1.3
# 4 1.72 1.1
# 5 2.06 1.2
# 6 2.68 1.3
```

notice that `df$l` can be calculated with

```
df$l[-nrow(df)] * df$g1[-1]
```

but this does not impute the missing.

Also notice to calculate `df$l`

```
# the second value is 
1.00 * 1.2

# the third value is  
1.20 * 1.3 == 1.00 * 1.2 * 1.3

# the fourth value is 
1.56 * 1.1 == 1.00 * 1.2 * 1.3 * 1.1
```

and so on

So we can calculate `df$l` using the cumulative product of `df$g1`. 
Then put these together.